# Extending contents of static list or dict in a derived making base method work on the derived version

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `Base` class that operates on some data and uses a static `dict`. I would like to make a `Derived` class that extends this `dict`. The underlying algorithm does not change it can operate in the same manner just need to have some more data. My way seem to work but I am concerned about performance.

```
class Base(object):
    static_types_mapping = {
          "params" : "namespace",
            "data" : "data",
            "type" : "blob",
          }

    def __init__(self):
        self.static_types_mapping = Base.static_types_mapping

    def algo(self, data):
        do_some_magic(data, self.static_types_mapping)

class Derived(Base):
    static_types_mapping = Base.static_types_mapping
    static_types_mapping.update( {"extra_field" : "fancy_type"} )

    def __init__(self):
        self.static_types_mapping = Derived.static_types_mapping
```

This way, I do not need to redefine `algo` to use derived type, because I am using local one. I also do not introduce unnecessary copies of dictionaries because of python's policy of using references whenever possible. I also extend the dictionary once, because it's in the "static" part of class definition.

My question is, is this logic right (maybe how can I test it)? Are there any better or more pythonic ways to do it?

This is intended to be used with python3.

Comment: I don't understand why you're defining `static_types_mapping` at class level only to immediately override it with an instance variable inside `__init__`.

Comment: Plus, of course, if you update without copying then you're updating all references.

Comment: @DanielRoseman As far as i under stand things, and I may be wrong, I am not overriding anything. I bind static dict reference, to a local. My intention is that the `algo` in `Base` needs to work in on the `Derived` version of `dict`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "bind static dict reference to a local".  You define `static_types_mapping` at class level, but then in `__init__` you immediately override that with a reference to the one in `Report`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I had bug there. I retyped code wrongly. Now it is like I meant it. `__init__` should use the version defined in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sharing a mutable dict between the base and derived class, without creating a copy. This will *not* work as you expect.

Use the `dict.copy()` method to create a new dict object for the subclass:

```
class Base(object):
    static_types_mapping = {
          "params" : "namespace",
            "data" : "data",
            "type" : "blob",
          }

    def algo(self, data):
        do_some_magic(data, self.static_types_mapping)

class Derived(Base):
    static_types_mapping = Base.static_types_mapping.copy()
    static_types_mapping.update( {"extra_field" : "fancy_type"} )
```

If the instance dictionaries are *meant* to be shared, there is no point in assigning an instance attribute here.

It is unclear what performance issue you are worried about here. Providing your algorithm with a per-class dictionary will save you a dictionary object build step, but the keys and values are stored as constants in the bytecode so the difference is negligible.

The same applies to looking up a class attribute when there is no instance attribute; Python is highly optimized to handle that case, there is little point in complicating your code for such a premature optimization.

Comment: I am sorry, I used copy pasted too much and for got to update the namespaces. I edited the code. `__init__` should use static variable defined in the same class. Even after. I won't copy contents of dictionary? I was worried about space. I like the code now, because it performs every step that is needed once, and then uses references. I am not sure if I can make the code clearer to get same functinoality.

Comment: You are copying across a reference to the same value, not creating a new dictionary. For immutable values such as strings, integers, tuples, etc. that's fine. You'd rebind to a new value when you want to change those, but for a *mutable* object, where you mutate the object *itself*, that is not so great when you don't expect the values to be shared.

Comment: I understand that now, if I touch `self.static_types_mapping` the change will be reflected across whole class. I could use `self.static_types_mapping = Derived.static_types_mapping.copy()` in `Derived::__init__`, to stay on the safe side, when some instance of Derived went berserk, but it costs memory. Am I right? Or the actual copy is made only in case of alteration?

Comment: Instance would have their own copy the moment `__init__` is called, not when the copy is altered.

Comment: So I guess there is no way, to mark it `non-mutable` or `copy-on-write`?

Comment: Not in the base `dict` type, no. You can always subclass it and create your own version; a dictionary that keeps a reference to the original, delegates all reads until you try to write, then creates a copy and uses that instead of the original.

Comment: But let me reiterate: Don't pre-maturely optimize.

Comment: I'm not; I was curious. I wrote my version and its already running. But for the future I want to understand how statements I write work, and you have great knowledge. That's why I asked. Thanks for your time and efforts.